# Get text but exclude node if it has a certain child in a for-each loop in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, nodes

I'm trying to get the following text

```
Divided into:
Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba (BQ, BES, 535)
Curaçao (CW, CUW, 531)
Sint Maarten (Dutch part) (SX, SXM, 534)
```

out of this source (excerpt):

```
<td>
  Divided into:<br />
  <a href="/wiki/Caribbean_Netherlands" title="Caribbean Netherlands">Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba</a> (<tt>BQ</tt>, <tt>BES</tt>, <tt>535</tt>) <sup id="cite_ref-7" class="reference">
    <a href="#cite_note-7">
      <span>[</span>note 4<span>]</span>
    </a>
  </sup><br />
  <a href="/wiki/Cura%C3%A7ao" title="Curaçao">Curaçao</a> (<tt>CW</tt>, <tt>CUW</tt>, <tt>531</tt>)<br />
  <a href="/wiki/Sint_Maarten" title="Sint Maarten">Sint Maarten (Dutch part)</a> (<tt>SX</tt>, <tt>SXM</tt>, <tt>534</tt>)
</td>
```

This is easily done with `<xsl:value select="td[4]"/>` (it's the 4th td element, and I'm looping over the surrounded `tr`s).

But I want to **exclude the text `[note 4]`**, so every `a` that has `span` children.

I tried `td[4]/node()[not(descendant::span)]`, but it only left `Divided into:`. `td[4][not(//span)]` gives always empty strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you match `td[4]/node()[not(descendant::span)]` you're matching the forth td that doesn't have a span descendant. Since your td[4] does have a span descendant,you're getting empty results.

What you need is is a template to match the td[4] descendant nodes that does text output:

```
<xsl:template match="td[4]/node()"> ... <xsl:template>  <!-- match descendant nodes of td[4] -->
```

and another template to specifically catch the span node:

```
    <xsl:template match="span | text()[preceding-sibling::span] | text()[following-sibling::span]"/>
```

Comment: Your proposed solution gives me a concatination of all text nodes (so `td[4]/node()` works), but `span` is not being suppressed. I also tried to drop all `span`s with `match="//span"` but nothing changed.

Comment: You're right. I've made a fix that will fix the problem. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I need to check if something else is messed up by matching `span` in general, but I guess I could use modes to avoid that.